# How to avoid code blocks within bullet list increasing the vertical line spacing?

Tags: r-markdown, markdown, pandoc

With the settings

```
output:
  github_document:
    toc: true
    number_sections: true
```

and

````
```{r, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(collapse = TRUE)
```
````

compare

```
# Test
* foo
* bar
* boo
```

with output

[image]

to

````
# Test
* foo
  ```{r, echo = TRUE}
  print("eg")
  ```
* bar
* boo
````

with output

[image]

and we can see that the vertical spacing has been changed without any command to do so. How can this be prevented?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider this quick workaround:

````
---
output:
  github_document:
    toc: true
    number_sections: true
---

```{css, echo = FALSE}
li>p {
    margin-top: 0;     # default value: 16px
  }
p, blockquote, ul, ol, dl, table, pre {
    margin-bottom: 0;  # default value: 16px
  }
```

```{r, include = FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(collapse = TRUE)
```
````

Output:
[image]

By default, code chunks in R Markdown are included in the tag `<div class="..." />` in the HTML output. When `<div>` element is embedded in the list, item content (foo) will be wrapped in the `<p>` tag. So, we need to set its CSS properties: `margin-top` and `margin-bottom` to the `0`.

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <p>foo</p>
        <div class="sourceCode" id="...">...</div>
    </li>
    .
    .
</ul>
```